# Out Of Memory error while executing mysqldump

Tags: mysql, adobe

I am getting the following error when trying to backup a database using mysqldump from the command prompt.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\bob>C:\Adobe\LiveCycle8.2\mysql\bin\mysqldump --quick --add-locks --lock-tables -c --default-character-set=utf8 --skip-opt -pxxxx -u adobe -r C:\Adobe\LiveCycle8.2\configurationManager\working\upgrade\mysql\adobe.sql -B adobe --port=3306 --host=localhost
mysqldump: Out of memory (Needed 10380928 bytes)
mysqldump: Got error: 2008: MySQL client ran out of memory when retrieving data from server
```

As you can see i am using the --quick and --skip-opt too; I can not figure out what is causing the issue.

The server log has the following messages

```
100420 15:16:39  InnoDB: Error: cannot allocate 4814100 bytes of memory for
InnoDB: a BLOB with malloc! Total allocated memory
InnoDB: by InnoDB 33427880 bytes. Operating system errno: 2
InnoDB: Check if you should increase the swap file or
InnoDB: ulimits of your operating system.
InnoDB: On FreeBSD check you have compiled the OS with
InnoDB: a big enough maximum process size.
100420 15:16:40  InnoDB: Warning: could not allocate 3814100 + 1000000 bytes to retrieve
InnoDB: a big column. Table name `adobe/tb_form_data`
```

Any help on this regard is highly appreciated

P.S: The backup works fine without any issues when i use the MYSQL Administrator, but since an external app( adobe livecycle installer) uses the above command to backup the database during install, i need to get this working.

These are my system details Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Enterprise Edition SP2 Intel Pentium 4, 2.80GHZ , 1.99 GB RAM. When i run the backup using the MYSQL Administrator i get a 11gb backup file

Thanks,
Nishaz Salam

Comment: Welcome to SO. Hmm. How about telling us more about your system and how much memory you actually have? How large is the database? At first glance, this looks like a plain "out of memory" error that should be fixed by adding more memory.

Comment: These are my system details
Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Enterprise Edition  SP2
Intel Pentium 4, 2.80GHZ , 1.99 GB RAM.
When i run the backup using the MYSQL Administrator i get a 11gb backup file.

Answer (score 0):

> cannot allocate 4814100 bytes of memory for a BLOB with malloc! Total allocated memory by InnoDB 33427880 bytes. Operating system errno: 2
> Check if you should increase the swap file or ulimits of your operating system.

Your system has 2 GB of RAM and the backup file is 11 GB. You will need to increase system swap paging file.

- Open System Properties.
- Choose Advanced then Performance Settings.
- In Virtual Memory settings, you should see the current page file size.
- This must be at minimum your RAM size (2 GB), but for this task I would recommend closer to 10 GB to 13 GB.